# Unable to reference a Library project - Android

Tags: android

Well, I wanted to create a Library project from my existing sources so that it would help me re-use code for the paid app that I have in mind. When I saw the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) on how this was to be done, I thought it was very simple.

Just mark the project as a Library project and it should be converted to one.

But when I tried referencing one of the base classes in an application, the app force closes with the following exceptions

> 02-04 21:50:06.765: E/AndroidRuntime(699): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in.my.package.name.R$layout

Let me give you some more info. I have referenced the Library project in the application and have also included the manifest entries with fully qualified activity names. I have a BaseActivity which has all the menu and re-usable code bits. The point where the above exception occurs is where I am trying to reference the layout file in this BaseActivity inside the library project.

> setContentView(R.layout.apphome);

What is it that I am missing or doing wrongly?

PS: I am just noticing that When I right click on my application and go to the android tab, there is a **red cross** instead of a **green tick** in the place where the library project is referenced. But there are no visible errors on the console or in the code of the project.

Comment: How did you add reference to this Android library project? There's reference section right below from where you checked your library project as one. Try using it if you didn't already.

Comment: Yup done all that. I think that's why I have mentioned the Developer guide's link in my post!!

Comment: I see, pardon me. In that case I can only say cleaning all projects in workspace may or may not fix your problem.

Comment: Tried that too bro. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you declare the library components in the library manifest or the apps manifest.  I recall having to declare it in the app at a minimum.

Comment: Yup, done that too as mentioned in the developer guide link in my post!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a known issue. 
Issue link [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656)

Hope Google guys resolve this problem in their next SDK release.

So to be clear, the problem was that my libraries had custom styling capabilities and that was the problem.